# How to add hidden neurons to a Pytorch RNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

How can I add hidden neurons to a Recurrent Neural Network in pytorch? In my understanding, torch.nn.RNN has n neurons with inputs being the input and the hidden state, where n is equal to the size of the hidden state.

How can I add additional layers before the neurons go back to the hidden state? E.g. If i only have 1 input and 1 output, but want to be able to model more complex functions?

I tried using the num_layers parameter but this just adds more layers of single neurons. I also tried using torch.nn.Sequential to stack individual RNNs with different sized inputs/outputs but this didnt work as Sequential objects dont seem to pass through additional parameters (h0, the initial hidden state).

Im trying to model f(x)=sin(x) with the initial hidden state beign the initial value of the sinewave (sin(x_0)), the inputs being x and the outputs being sin(x).

Answer (score 1):

You can't define rnn without defining hidden neurons.

Lets look at the [official](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) example:

```
class RNNTutorial(Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size,
                 output_size):
        super(RNNTutorial, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        size_sum = input_size + hidden_size
        self.i2h = Linear(size_sum, hidden_size)
        self.i2o = Linear(size_sum, output_size)
        self.softmax = LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, input_, hidden_):
        combined = cat(tensors=(input_, hidden_), dim=1)
        hidden_ = self.i2h(input=combined)
        hidden_ = relu(hidden_)
        output = self.i2o(input=combined)
        output = self.softmax(input=output)
        return output, hidden_

    def init_hidden(self):
        return zeros(1, self.hidden_size)
```

Above is a two-layer RNN structure. On the 1st layer

```
self.i2h = Linear(size_sum, hidden_size)
```

The hidden neuron input size: `size_sum` and the output `hidden_size`

how to add neuron? You can change the parameter values.

For instance: `size_sum + 1` now you add one more hidden neuron.

Comment: I'm talking about torch.nn.RNN which is optimized because it's called on the whole sequence at once. It only has the parameters input_size and hidden_size because it's output is the hidden state.

Comment: My answer is also a `rnn` example. In pytorch, there are multiple ways of defining `rnn` networks.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html

Comment: Yes the link you pasted is one example. Here is the 2nd example:  https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html

Comment: But why does my example have no hidden neurons? Or how would I use it if my input and desired output both only had a size of sequence_length x 1 x batch?

Comment: But let's take a look at your example: I assume `rnn = nn.RNN(10, 20, 2)` is your example right? The parameter 10 is your input size, the parameter 20 is your hidden neuron size (the value you want to change) and 2 is your layer size.

Comment: If your input is `sequence_length x 1 x batch` this is related to LSTM. RNN is a way simpler compared to LSTM. Because RNN's are usually 2-dim.

Comment: If I wanted my rnn to calculate sin(x) with the sequence being x = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4,) i would have to ```rnn = nn.RNN(1, 1, 2)``` as I only have one input, x, and one output, sin(x). But this would only have one neuron inside so it probably won't be able to model the sinewave. To answer your question about dimensions, in the documentation of nn.RNN it says the input has to have the shape (sequence_length, input_size, batch_num)